# Jquery :contain selector exclude some div from conditions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to disable href and onclick event if  tag contain same value as per passed parameter, following is my script but it disable all a tag that match with given word.

I want to match exact string and remove href attribute on match.

following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[value *= '<?php echo($tag) ?>']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("a:contains('<?php echo($tag) ?>')").removeAttr("onclick");
    $("a:contains('<?php echo($tag) ?>')").removeAttr("href");  

    //$( "div" ).not( ".green, #qm0" ).removeAttr("onclick");
    //$( "div" ).not( ".green, #qm0" ).removeAttr("href");

    });
</script>
```

Comment: page has a lots of html but I don't want to disable link on specific div with id="qm0" all other links that matches condition will be disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to filter some elements based on some value and want to apply another filter for excluding this from some container.

Jquery Selector

```
$('a').not("#some_id a").filter(function(){
           return (/string_to_be_matched/i).test($(this).text())
})// .any valid chain-able operation.
```

**Explanation**:

`$('a').not("#some_id a")` will give you all the anchor tags from the DOM except anchor tags from the container with id `some_id`.

Then you can apply filter to match some string value on these selected anchor tags,

```
.filter(function(){
           return (/string_to_be_matched/i).test($(this).text())
})
```

Replace `string_to_be_matched` with your string value. In your case perhaps some `php echo`

PS: Make sure that your elements are **added to the DOM** before you apply above selectors.
i.e. use [$.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) or if you have static content have the script at the **end of the page**.